# Need to use php 5.2.9 with xampp 1.8.1 components

Tags: php, apache, xampp

My website is using Xampp version 1.7.1 and it contains apache 2.2 and php 5.2.9, 
**I got a requirement from client, to change apache 2.2 to 2.4**.

Our application is a product and it is delivering as an installation package to clients.And we are using Xampp standalone version in the installation

So i used latest Xampp 1.8.1 which already have this apache 2.4.But the latest Xampp version using the latest php engine(php 5.4) .So our site is not working with this latest version (earlier it was php 5.2.9).

To fix this issue i replaced php folder in latest Xampp with older version php.
and used patch delivered by the Apache Lounge
[ https://www.apachelounge.com/download/ ] - https://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/modules-2.4/php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.2-win32.zip

Everything working fine now but there is an issue with  mcrypt extension
I have enabled the mcrypt extension in the php.ini. But this is not getting enabled. I am getting error while using the mcrypt_decrypt() in php.

Comment: Enable PHP error logging and check if there are any startup errors in that log. You need to find out the exact error message if you want to quickly troubleshoot this.

Comment: Fix your code instead of downgrading to the version that _works_.

Comment: It is a big live project and we cannot do these fixes within minutes.And we need to give a build within three weeks

Comment: You can see http://meows.us/my-life/running-multiple-versions-of-xampp-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [mcrypt from sourceforge.net](http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/)

You may find additional details on [requirements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php) and [installation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php) link

Do ensure that file `php_mcrypt.dll` is in *xampp/php/ext/* directory alongwith `libmcrypt.dll` in *xampp/apache/bin* in case you are using windows..